# Is top K index possible in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a collection *users*. It only have one field *score* (except for the id field). There're 1m documents in it.

If I build an index on *score*, the index will have 1m entries. But I only interest in top 10 scores, is it possible to build an top 10 index on that field?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always build a descending index for the `scores` field, and use limit.

Sorting descendingly, and limiting to 10 will do the job.

In the example below is a collection of 1 million documents, each has `score` field.

```js
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

run().catch(console.error);

async function run () {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

  const userSchema = new Schema({
    score: Number
  });

  const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

  const users = Array.from({ length: 1000 * 1000 }).map((v, i) => ({ score: i + 1 }));
  await User.init();

  await User.insertMany(users);

  const before = Date.now();
  await User.find().sort({ score: -1 }).limit(10);
  const after = Date.now();

  console.log(`Query took: ${after - before}ms.`);
}
```

Without having an index on the `score` field, the output is:

```
Query took: 1468ms.
```

With [the descending index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#create-an-index):

```
Query took: 9ms.
```

Here's how you can [create an index in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

Comment: The problem is, if I build an index including the whole 1m docs, it takes too much space. So I'd like to only keep  top 10 docs.

Comment: I see. I think there is currently no way to keep an index of only the top K documents in MongoDB.